# User input creates Popup image

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I am not a coder or developer and have hired a developer from Fiver to make some modifications to an html5 website template that I'm modifying as a game for my daughter so only she will see it.  The developer is really struggling  with a javascript image popup and I'm looking for help

What I want to happen

- on button click Enter code box pops up.  If user enters 1234 image max1.jpg pops up
- on button click Enter code box pops up.  If user enters 2345 image max2.jpg pops up

### Below is the developers code which looks a bit clunky and does not work well - the images are cut off.  Any help would be appreciated and do the images sizes need to be specified somewhere?

Button Code

```
<a class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger" href="#about" id="but" onclick="myFunction()">CODE</a>
```

---

In Body

```
<img id="image1" src="assets/img/max1.jpg" width="100%"   style="visibility: hidden;">
<img id="image2" src="assets/img/max2.jpg" width="100%"   style="visibility: hidden;">
<img id="image3" src="assets/img/max3.jpg" width="100%"   style="visibility: hidden;">
```

---

```
<script>
   var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
   var m1 = document.getElementById("m1");
   var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
   var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
   span.onclick = function() {
     modal.style.display = "none";
   }

   function myFunction() {


    var code = prompt("Enter Code:", "");
    
     if (code == "1234") 
     {
         // m1.style.width = "70%";
     document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "none";


          document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "block";

     document.getElementById("image1").style.visibility = "visible";
     // document.getElementById("image1").style.width = "100%";
     // document.getElementById("image1").style.height = "100%";
     modal.style.display = "block";
    
     } 

     else if (code == "2345") {
         // m1.style.width = "70%";
     document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "none";

     document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "block";

     document.getElementById("image2").style.visibility = "visible";
     // document.getElementById("image2").style.width = "100%";
     // document.getElementById("image2").style.height = "100%";
     modal.style.display = "block";
     }

        else if (code == "3456") {
         // m1.style.width = "70%";
     document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("image2").style.display = "none";


     document.getElementById("image3").style.display = "block";

     document.getElementById("image3").style.visibility = "visible";
     // document.getElementById("image2").style.width = "100%";
     // document.getElementById("image2").style.height = "100%";
     modal.style.display = "block";
     }


       else if (code == "4567") {
         window.open("Instructions.pdf", '_blank');
       }
       else if (code == "5678") {
         window.open("Instructions.pdf", '_blank');
       }

       }       
</script>
```